# How to control new browser tab using Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How can I control a new tab opened with `chrome.browser.openTab({url:""}, function () { });`?
Control in the sense, things we do with JavaScript like change the URL of the tab, get element by ID and change element attributes, etc.

Is it possible within a Chrome app or do I have to create a Chrome app plus an extension and control everything using message passing?

Comment: Only extensions can do that. Apps don't have such API as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be a Chrome App controlling contents of a Chrome browser tab, then I think what you suggest at the end is the best option: Chrome app communicates with Chrome extension via message passing and Chrome extension modifies the page.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Probably this does not fit your use case, but if the website could be displayed from the Chrome app, you could use a `<webview>` tag, the website would not be sandboxed, and you could control its contents using `webview.executeScript` and the `contentload` event

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#example
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-contentload